Is grounding an outlet only to its box enough?
There's an outlet in the front hall of my house near Atlanta, GA. I noticed scorch marks on the face, so I decided to investigate it a bit. My outlet tester indicated an open ground.
When I opened up the outlet, I was surprised by what I saw. The outlet's hot and neutral terminals were connected to two individual 10 AWG wires, and the outlet's ground terminal was connected to a ground screw on the metal box. I had never seen an outlet wired with anything other than Romex before.
The two individual 10 AWG wires ran to a another outlet on the other side of the wall where I confirmed they were connected to the hot and neutral wires of a circuit.
The outlet was a NEMA 5-20.
Was this outlet installed in a code-compliant manner?




Those wire colours seem be from a conduit wire system.  If so and the conduit is metal, that is being used as the ground connection back to the panel.  I would check the breaker powering this circuit is only 20 amps, since 10 gauge is used for 30 amp circuits,but larger wire is only bad for wallets.

Photo angle might be deceiving me, but were those stranded wires backstabbed? And is this a 20A breaker?

The wires were not in a conduit. The wires were held with a screw-down clamping system on the back of the outlet. Yes, this was on a 20 A breaker.

What caused the scorch marks ?

@Criggie I have no idea. I just moved in to this house. The scorch marks were there from before I moved in.

Note that using 2 different holes for cables causes heating of the box by eddy currents

No, it's not installed in a code-compliant manner. For one thing, the conductors are passing through box mounting holes! That particular kind of conductor belongs in conduit, which should be entering through one of the circular knock-out holes in the box.
We can see the box is mounted to the drywall with simple sheet metal mounting tabs, and based on the hack with the two supply conductors, we can be almost certain that box isn't actually grounded.
As for your title question: yes, it's sufficient to ground an outlet only to its box -- if, and only if, the box itself is properly grounded.

To add to Greg's answer, it's important to note when and where you can ground to the box.
Metal boxes are grounded when

You've bonded the box to a ground wire that connects back to the main panel neutral (directly or through a grounded subpanel). If this is done via cable, you'll have a NM clamp where the cable comes in
You're using grounded metal raceway or conduit

Neither of these apply to your photo. The easiest way to tell is none of the knockouts are removed. It looks like they have THHN wires fished through the back of the box. This raises a deeper question for you: how was that THHN fished to this box? Normally, THHN is run inside conduit (there's only the outer sheath of insulation between you a 120v). If this isn't conduit, you'll need to replace it with NM cable by boxing it off somewhere upstream and re-running it. Or, worst of all, it should have been in conduit (i.e. you live near Chicago) and someone cheated badly.

The wires coming into this box had a thankfully short run of about 2 feet to an outlet on the other side of the wall. I pulled out the existing wires and replaced them with some NM cable.

@KurtTomlinson good work - is the other box grounded?  The one on the other side of the wall?    If this outlet was installed by a PO then you might be wise to methodically check every outlet in the house.  Doubt everything, trust nothing.

@Criggie Yes, the other box was grounded properly, and now the box in question is too. I've been replacing all the switches and outlets in the house. The previous owner had replaced all the switch and outlet covers with white ones but left the almond switches and outlets in place. I'm replacing all the switches and outlets with white ones so they match the covers. This makes it easy to see which devices I've inspected and which ones are left :).
